# Null Pointer Exception in setting a value to TextView

Tags: android

```
TextView t =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.place); 
t.setText("A");
```

i call the above code inside `onCreate()` method. My activity is a ListActivity. But why this gives me the following error

```
05-04 14:21:40.840: E/AndroidRuntime(16168): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

and here is the XML where i defined TextView

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/place"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:focusable="false"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_gravity="left"/>
```

and how to fix it?

Comment: findViewById() returns the view if found or null otherwise.

Comment: @dinesh707 can u post ur onCreate methode code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class yourclass extends Activity{
    TextView t;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.patient);
            t =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.place); 
            t.setText("A");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hey i guess You have not set the proper layout to the list view.

in the onCreate of the ListActivity set a layout which will be somewhat like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient_unselected"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/blacklist_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:divider="@drawable/seperator"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and the row item layout should be different.